# Using PIVOT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How can i convert below using PIVOT

[image]

as

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s a bit messy, but here it is.

First of all I use the rank() function to know the position (1,2 or 3) of the ErrorField.
With all that, I use that number for the Pivot.
You need two pivots and a join between them.

```
WITH AuxTable (Data_Error_Key, ErrorField, ErrorValue, NumeroError) 
AS
(
SELECT Data_Error_Key, ErrorField, ErrorValue, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Data_Error_Key ORDER BY Data_Error_Key, ErrorField)
FROM dbo.TempTable
)
SELECT TablaErrorField.Data_Error_Key, ErrorField1, ErrorValue1,ErrorField2,ErrorValue2,  ErrorField3,
      ErrorValue3
FROM 
(
    SELECT Data_Error_Key, [1] as ErrorField1, [2] as ErrorField2, [3] as ErrorField3
    FROM (
    SELECT Data_Error_Key,NumeroError, ErrorField
    FROM AuxTable) P
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX (ErrorField)
    FOR NumeroError IN ([1], [2], [3])
    ) AS pvt) As TablaErrorField
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Data_Error_Key, [1] as ErrorValue1, [2] as ErrorValue2, [3] as ErrorValue3
    FROM (
    SELECT Data_Error_Key,NumeroError, ErrorValue
    FROM AuxTable) P
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX (ErrorValue)
    FOR NumeroError IN ([1], [2], [3])
    ) AS pvt) as TablaErrorValue
ON TablaErrorField.Data_Error_Key= TablaErrorValue.Data_Error_Key
```

All this assuming you need only 3 pairs of ErrorField/ErrorValue. Otherwise, you should take a look at my response in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679433/pivot-unpivot-in-sql-server-2008/2700959) question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do that with the SQL Server PIVOT function. That function always assumes and requires some kind of an aggregate function (COUNT, AVG) on a numeric value - you can't just transpose rows to columns.

In your case, if you know your error fields in advance, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
   ErrorKey,
   [Field1] AS Field1, [Field2] AS Field2, [Field10] AS Field10, 
   [Field11] AS Field11, [Field13] as Field13, [Field14] as Field14, 
   [Field15] as Field15, [Field21] as field21
FROM 
   (SELECT ErrorKey, ErrorField, ErrorValue
    FROM Errors) e
PIVOT
(
COUNT (ErrorValue)
FOR ErrorField IN
    ( [Field1], [Field2], [Field10], [Field11], [Field13], 
      [Field14], [Field15], [Field21] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.ErrorKey
```

This would produce an output something like this:

```
ErrorKey    Field1  Field2  Field10 Field11 Field13 Field14 Field15 field21
  1           1       1        1      0        0      0        0       0
  2           0       0        0      1        1      1        0       0
  3           0       0        0      0        0      0        1       1
```

This would give you the count of error in a particular field, for each error key.