# Unpivoting multiple, repeated columns with multiple (denormalized) values

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns, unpivot

I have a table with multiple columns like this...

```
+-------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Name  |     Email      | Address | Order1  | Shipping1 |   Date1    |  Order2   | Shipping2 |   Date2    | Order3  | Shipping3 |   Date3    |
+-------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| John  | john@abcd.com  |     123 | Rock    |       123 | 02/11/2017 | Computer  |       123 | 07/11/2017 | Pen     |       123 | 12/11/2017 |
| Jane  | jane@abcd.com  |     234 | Scissor |       234 | 03/11/2017 | Laptop    |       234 | 08/11/2017 | Pencil  |       234 | 13/11/2017 |
| Julie | julie@abcd.com |     345 | Paper   |       345 | 04/11/2017 | Mouse     |       345 | 09/11/2017 | Clips   |       345 | 14/11/2017 |
| Jaden | jaden@abcd.com |     456 | Spock   |       456 | 05/11/2017 | Screen    |       456 | 10/11/2017 | Pins    |       456 | 15/11/2017 |
| Jabba | jabba@abcd.com |     678 | Lizard  |       678 | 06/11/2017 | Pen Drive |       678 | 11/11/2017 | Notepad |       678 | 16/11/2017 |
+-------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

And I want to unpivot the columns into rows like this in T-SQL...

```
+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Name  |     Email      | Address |   Order   | Shipping |    Date    |
+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| John  | john@abcd.com  |     123 | Rock      |      123 | 02/11/2017 |
| John  | john@abcd.com  |     123 | Computer  |      123 | 07/11/2017 |
| John  | john@abcd.com  |     123 | Pen       |      123 | 12/11/2017 |
| Jane  | jane@abcd.com  |     234 | Scissor   |      234 | 03/11/2017 |
| Jane  | jane@abcd.com  |     234 | Laptop    |      234 | 08/11/2017 |
| Jane  | jane@abcd.com  |     234 | Pencil    |      234 | 13/11/2017 |
| Julie | julie@abcd.com |     345 | Paper     |      345 | 04/11/2017 |
| Julie | julie@abcd.com |     345 | Mouse     |      345 | 09/11/2017 |
| Julie | julie@abcd.com |     345 | Clips     |      345 | 14/11/2017 |
| Jaden | jaden@abcd.com |     456 | Spock     |      456 | 05/11/2017 |
| Jaden | jaden@abcd.com |     456 | Screen    |      456 | 10/11/2017 |
| Jaden | jaden@abcd.com |     456 | Pins      |      456 | 15/11/2017 |
| Jabba | jabba@abcd.com |     678 | Lizard    |      678 | 06/11/2017 |
| Jabba | jabba@abcd.com |     678 | Pen Drive |      678 | 11/11/2017 |
| Jabba | jabba@abcd.com |     678 | Notepad   |      678 | 16/11/2017 |
+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I googled and checked other posts related to this but unable to get three values. :(

**Appreciate the help!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIVOT / UNPIVOT in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679433/pivot-unpivot-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need to necessarily use `UNPIVOT` here at all.

You'll be able to UNION the three denormalized Orders back into a flattened output, like so:

```
SELECT name, Email, Address, Order1 AS Order, Shipping1 as Shipping, Date1 AS Date
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT name, Email, Address, Order2, Shipping2, Date2
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT name, Email, Address, Order3, Shipping3, Date3
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Name, Date;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56ec9e/4)

(The column names are set by the first select in the `UNION`, and the `ORDER` is applied to the final UNIONed data)